# Regression inference: Exclude factors

Tags: regression, inference

thanks for everybody who was reading through this. 
In the meanwhile i was checking in detail every line in the code. The most recent changes visible here *are correct*.
So this question is solved. I leave this piece here for everyone who wants to take a look.

In the lesson pdf of [Victor Chernozhukov](http://www.mit.edu/~vchern/), i have seen that it is apparently possible to extract the influence of a single variable on a result with regression analyses.

So i took notes in the last half year, each time when i was driving my Prius, how much he would consume. And I switched between two gas types: E10 (10% alcohol, the rest is 95 normal gas); and SP98 (which is sold as "super" in some countries).

My expectation is to find that my car consumes less with the stronger fuel, and more with E10.
However - there is lots of influence by the climatization, weather, speed and travel length.

I have uploaded the data table and my test code to git hub:
[check out my repository, it contains the data and a jupyter notebook](https://github.com/Anderas2/prius_gas_type)

I am absolutely NOT sure if i did it right.

In theory it works like this:
You exclude the target variable (consumption) and the variable to-be-extracted (gas type) from the feature vector.
With the rest of the features you fit one linear model on the target (r1), and another one on the to-be-extracted (r2).

Finally you fit a third linear model with the residuals of r2 as features and the residuals of r1 as target. The outcome is the influence of the to-be-extracted feature (gas type) on the target variable (consumption).

Here is the most important part of the code, in case you don't want to head over to my repository:

```
prediction_values = ['distance', 'speed', 'speedsquare', 'temp_diff', 'AC', 'rain']

X = df[prediction_values].values
Y = df['consume'].values
Y_gas = df['gas_type_num'].values

# apply regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
rgr = LinearRegression()
rgr.fit(X, Y)

# apply again, this time trained on gas type
rgr_gas = LinearRegression()
rgr_gas.fit(X, Y_gas)

# get the residuals out (they represent the left-over not-explained variance)
Y_residuals = Y - rgr.predict(X)
X_gas_residuals = Y - rgr_gas.predict(X)
rgr_inference = LinearRegression()

# fit the residuals to get the influence of the gas type.
# reshape(-1,1) is necessary since scikit 19 if you have a single feature.
rgr_inference.fit(X_gas_residuals.reshape(-1,1), Y_residuals) 
difference = rgr_inference.coef_[0] # difference = 0.84
```

There is only one value coming out, but it is coming out as a list of one value,
so i take number zero.

And, real world outcome: as the care consumes 0.84 liters more with E10, it means that 100 km cost roughly 60 cents more. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile i was able to solve the problem i had:
How to extract the influence of a single factor on the target variable.

It works if the single factor is independent from other factors. Then, just follow the code above, i reworked it accordingly. 
If you want to see a complete walkthrough, head over to my code repository linked in the question.

Thanks everybody who was taking his time to read this

Andreas